# spltting the row data with cursor and insert data into different columns

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I have string like

```
'spla - asqlserver 2008 #P1           Q TY 1
:SPLA-WINSV  QWSRSTDA#P29- 9 QTY2:SP
LA-WINSVMSTDA #P29-999QTY2:SPLA-WINSVRSTD-sqlserver 2008#P 9  9 9 QT Y3:SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P 
9-999QTY4 : SPLA-WINSVRSvr3# 59-99 Q TY5:SP -WI  Sa 1 #P    999 Q T Y6'
```

and I wrote function  like

```
ALTER function [dbo].[string_splitting_WORKING]
(
 @STR VARCHAR(MAX),
 @DELIMITER CHAR(1)

)
RETURNS @Result Table
(
Output varchar(max)
)
as 
begin
DECLARE @Index int
declare @Output varchar(max)
select @index = 1
IF @STR IS NULL RETURN
WHILE @Index ! = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Str)
        IF @Index != 0
            SELECT @Output = LEFT(@Str, @Index - 1)
            --ltrim(ltrim(substring(@Str,0,charindex('#',@Str)))) 
            --LEFT(@Str, @Index - 1)
        ELSE
            SELECT @Output = @Str
        INSERT INTO @Result(Output) VALUES (@Output)
        SELECT @Str = RIGHT(@Str, LEN(@Str) - @Index)
        IF LEN(@Str) = 0 
        BREAK
    END
    RETURN
END;
```

when u pass the string into the function like this

```
select * from [dbo].[string_splitting_WORKING]('SAQa # P 1      9 s-9    9 9 9  1:SPLA-WINSVRSTDA#P29-999QTY2
:SPLA-WINS VMSTDA#P 29-99 9Q TY2:SPLA-WggaerINSVRSTD# P3 9-9 99 9 Q TY3:SPLA-WINSVRSTD#P49-9999QTY4:SPLA-WINSVRSvr3#P59-9999QTY5:SPLA-WINSVRSat1#P69-9999QTY6 :',':')
```

I am getting output like this

```
SAQa # P 1      9 s-9    9 9 9  1
SPLA-WINSVRSTDA#P29-999QTY2  
SPLA-WINS VMSTDA#P 29-99 9Q TY2
SPLA-WggaerINSVRSTD# P3 9-9 99 9 Q TY3
SPLA-WINSVRSTD#P49-9999QTY4
SPLA-WINSVRSvr3#P59-9999QTY5
SPLA-WINSVRSat1#P69-9999QTY6
```

I wrote another function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RowStringSplit] 
( 
        @RowData varchar(8000), 
        @Delimiter varchar(5) 
)   
RETURNS @RtnValue table  
(      ServerName varchar(1000),
        PoNumber varchar(500),
        Qty varchar(100))  
AS   
BEGIN  
        Declare @Cnt int 
        Set @Cnt = 1 

        While (Charindex(@Delimiter,@RowData)>0) 

     Begin 
                Insert Into @RtnValue (Servername,PoNumber)--,Qty) 

                Select  ServerName = ltrim(ltrim(Substring(@RowData,0,Charindex('#',@RowData)))),
                        --PoNumber   = ltrim(ltrim(substring(@RowData,charindex('#',@RowData)+1,CHARINDEX(':',@RowData)-1))) --1
                        --PoNumber   =  substring(@RowData,charindex('#',@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))                          --2

                        PoNumber = substring(@RowData,charindex('#',@RowData)+1,charindex('QTY',REVERSE(@RowData))+ @Cnt)--3

                          --PoNumber = case charindex('#',@RowData),1) when 0 then @RowData
                          --           else
                          --               substring(@RowData,1,charindex('QTY',@RowData,1)-1 

                          --Qty      = substring(@RowData,charindex('QTY',@RowData),Charindex(':',@RowData)-26)

             Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@Delimiter,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
             Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1 
      End 
       Insert  Into @RtnValue (ServerName)                                  
        Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))
        Return 

END
```

and I am getting output like this

```
     ServerName              PoNumber  Qty
------------------------------------------------
spla - asqlserver 2008        P        NULL
SPLA-WINSV  QWSRSTDA          P2       NULL
SP  LA-WINSVMSTDA             P29      NULL
SPLA-WINSVRSTD-sqlserver 2008 P 9      NULL
SPLA-WINSVRSTD                P   9    NULL
SPLA-WINSVRSvr3                59-99   NULL
SP -WI  Sa 1                  P    99  NULL
```

but the requirement is if i remove the data from serverName column  It has to show blank and If 
I increase the data in the serverName column It should increase but I am getting that
but the problem is if I remove or add the data after # until qty that is from p upto qty the reset Its not comming exactly and last I need only number in the qty column

will u help me how to get the proper output by using function or procedure to split that string

from anand

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Looks like it's returning the correct output for your input string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test (@a VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS @RtnValue table  (
    ServerName varchar(1000),
    PoNumber varchar(500),
    Qty varchar(100)
)
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @part1 VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @part2 VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @part3 VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @i INT


    SELECT @a = LTRIM(RTRIM(@a))
    SELECT @i = PATINDEX('%#%', @a)
    IF @i = 0 SELECT @i = LEN(@a)
    SELECT @part1 = LEFT(@a, @i - 1)

    SELECT @a = RIGHT(@a, LEN(@a) - @i)

    SELECT @a = REPLACE(@a, ' ', '')
    SELECT @i = PATINDEX('%QTY%', @a)
    IF @i > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @part2 = LEFT(@a, @i - 1)
        SELECT @part3 = RIGHT(@a, LEN(@a) - LEN(@part2) - 3)
    END
    ELSE 
        SELECT @part2 = @a

    INSERT @RtnValue
    SELECT @part1, @part2, @part3

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Execute it together with your function named `string_splitting_WORKING`:

```
select  t.*
from [dbo].[string_splitting_WORKING]('spla - asqlserver 2008 #P1           Q TY 1
:SPLA-WINSV  QWSRSTDA#P29- 9 QTY2:SP
LA-WINSVMSTDA #P29-999QTY2:SPLA-WINSVRSTD-sqlserver 2008#P 9  9 9 QT Y3:SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P 
9-999QTY4 : SPLA-WINSVRSvr3# 59-99 Q TY5:SP -WI  Sa 1 #P    999 Q T Y6'
,':')
CROSS APPLY dbo.test([Output]) t
```

It outputs:

```
ServerName                     PoNumber Qty
------------------------------------------------
spla - asqlserver 2008          P1            1  
SPLA-WINSV  QWSRSTDA            P29-9         2
SP  LA-WINSVMSTDA               P29-999       2
SPLA-WINSVRSTD-sqlserver 2008   P999          3
SPLA-WINSVRSTD                  P  9-999      4
SPLA-WINSVRSvr3                 59-99         5
SP -WI  Sa 1                    P999          6
```